# Animate Android ListView to slide up and down like the notification list

Tags: android, listview, animation

I want to include a ListView in my Android (2.2) application similar to the notification list that is coming from the top. Here I want it from bottom. The list should show always the top part and when slided up enlarge to 80% of the screen. When slided down, it should go back in its original size.

I tried several alternatives which did not work:

- Tweed animations always enlarge the part that is visible, not the
  real content
- Manual slide up in steps with an animation loop with
  onAnimationRepeat as it each time has to calculate the full layout
  after resizing, each step is slow and so the moving is quite bad
- Layout animations seem not to be a solution as the view is always
  visible and so it can not be animated during showing up.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the [Android Sliding Drawer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.html):

It will slide from the bottom, and you can place a ListView inside it.

It should look something like this:

[image]

[Here](http://w2davids.wordpress.com/android-damn-that-sliding-drawer/) is a tutorial:

Comment: thanks a lot. I was working for days on that. As I wanted to have a part of the list view visible, I changed the handle to a RelativeLayout containing the first list entry and my real handle image as background. I guess this is the best way as I did not find anything for that in the docu for SlidingDrawer

Comment: actually I found that my above to put the first list entry in the idea was not the best. So I took the solution  [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11492311/make-slidingdrawers-contents-part-always-visible) actually struggling a bit with all the modifications - but it worked and is great...