# want to call when you swipe any list item in android listview

Tags: android, android-listview, android-contacts, swipe-gesture

[image]

Hi want to implement the functionality to call any contact from listview using swipe functionality as below image in android.

How can i achieve this in android?

Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I think You want to sliding drawer on Listview following links are explain how to achieve this one:

Tutorial link :http://w2davids.wordpress.com/android-damn-that-sliding-drawer/

Stack Overflow post :[Android - ListView slide left/right like Samsung contact ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9321016/android-listview-slide-left-right-like-samsung-contact-listview)

[Animate Android ListView to slide up and down like the notification list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12129822/animate-android-listview-to-slide-up-and-down-like-the-notification-list)

Another Tutorial another link below:
http://android-coding-tuts.blogspot.in/2012/02/custom-listview-with-sliding-view-for.html