# Make the slidingdrawer's content part always be drawn

Tags: android, slidingdrawer

My issue is absolutely described here: [Make SlidingDrawer's content's part always visible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11492311/make-slidingdrawers-contents-part-always-visible). But I can not post a comment, so I post a new question.
I did extend SlidingDrawer like Ixxx, but it doesn't work.
Here is my XML file

```
<com.example.slidingdrawerex.ExtendedSlidingDrawer
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:bottomOffset="-50dp"
    android:content="@+id/content"
    android:handle="@+id/handle"
    android:topOffset="200dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@id/handle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/menu_drawer" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@id/content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
</com.example.slidingdrawerex.ExtendedSlidingDrawer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution. YOu have modify it little. Set Visibiblity of "outSide View" according to your need. go through it. 
https://github.com/darvds/RibbonMenu

Comment: Thanks for replying! But, it is not my issue.